# llenar v-select en vue desde api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api, select

Estoy tratando de llenar mi select con vue desde una api, pero no logro el resultado que necesito, traigo los datos desde una api, datos que llegan perfectamente sin problemas, pero al tratar de pasar los datos al v-select no se cargan, este es parte de mi codigo, dentro de ello quiero cargar en nombre y pasar a la base de datos el id de la comuna que trae desde la api...

```
<template>
  <div id="cliente-edit-tab-info">

    <vx-card>

    <form @submit.prevent="agregar">

        <!-- Content Row -->
        <div class="vx-row">
        <div class="vx-col md:w-1/2 w-full">
            <vs-input class="w-full mt-4" label="Rut" v-model="cliente.rut" v-validate="'required|alpha_num'" name="rut" />
            <span class="text-danger text-sm"  v-show="errors.has('dni')">{{ errors.first('dni') }}</span>

            <div class="mt-4">
            <label class="vs-input--label">Comuna</label>
                <v-select multiple
                        :value.sync="comunas.id"
                        :options="comunas.name">
                </v-select>
              <!--  <option v-for="(comuna, index) in comunas" :key="index">
                    {{comunas.name}}
                </option> -->
                <!-- <v-select v-model="status_local" :clearable="false" :options="statusOptions" v-validate="'required'" name="communes_id" :dir="$vs.rtl ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'" /> -->
                <!-- <span class="text-danger text-sm"  v-show="errors.has('communes_id')">{{ errors.first('communes_id') }}</span> -->
            </div>

            <vs-input class="w-full mt-4" label="Email" v-model="cliente.correo" type="email" v-validate="'required|email'" name="correo" />
            <span class="text-danger text-sm"  v-show="errors.has('correo')">{{ errors.first('correo') }}</span>
        </div>


        <div class="vx-col md:w-1/2 w-full">

             <div class="mt-4">
                <vs-input class="w-full mt-4" label="Edificio/Condominio" v-model="cliente.nombre" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" name="nombre" />
                <span class="text-danger text-sm"  v-show="errors.has('nombre')">{{ errors.first('nombre') }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <vs-input class="w-full mt-4" label="Dirección" v-model="cliente.direccion" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" name="direccion" />
                <span class="text-danger text-sm"  v-show="errors.has('direccion')">{{ errors.first('direccion') }}</span>
            </div>

            <vs-input class="w-full mt-4" label="Telefono" v-model="cliente.telefono" v-validate="'alpha_spaces'" name="telefono" />
            <span class="text-danger text-sm"  v-show="errors.has('telefono')">{{ errors.first('telefono') }}</span>

        </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Save & Reset Button -->
            <div class="vx-row">
                <div class="vx-col w-full">
                    <div class="mt-8 flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end">
                    <vs-button class="ml-auto mt-2" @click="agregar"  >Guardar</vs-button>
                   <vs-button class="ml-4 mt-2" type="border" color="warning" @click="reset_data">Resetear</vs-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    </vx-card>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'
import vSelect from 'vue-select'

export default {
  components: {
    vSelect
  },

  data() {
    return {

        clientes: [],
        cliente:  {name: '', email: '', dni: ''},
        comunas:[],
    }
  },
    computed: {
        comunas(){
            return Object.values(this.comunas);
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.created()
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/api/clientes/create')
        .then(res => {
            this.comunas = res.data;
        })
    },
    methods: {
    agregar(){
        //console.log(this.user.name, this.user.email, this.user.dni, this.user.id);
        const params = {
            name:  this.cliente.name,
            email: this.cliente.email,
            dni:   this.cliente.dni,
            }
        axios.post('/api/clientes/store', params)
            .then( res =>{
                this.clientes.push(res.data);
                this.$router.push('/apps/clientes/clientes-list');
            })
    },
    },
}
</script>
```

busco cargar el nombre de la comuna y guardar en la base de datos el id de esa comuna.

así retorna el api:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí comparto mi código completo para revisión mas detallada

Comment: Debes revisar que `comunas` cuando lo llenas con los datos del API sea un `array` de objetos, fuera bueno que colocaras lo que te retorna el API

Comment: lo es amigo!

```{
"comunas": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Arica"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Camarones"
},```

Comment: porque tienes dos variables con el mismo nombre? O sea tienes `comunas` en `data` y `computed`. Puede  haber conflicto

Comment: tienes que poner el código completo, estoy recreando lo que tienes y faltan los métodos. y el template no esta completo

Comment: ahora comparti mi codigo completo amigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que options debe recibir un array y le estas pasando un objeto y dentro de ese objeto recien tienes el array necesitado. Intenta pasandole comunas.comunas al options. Tu v-select quedaria algo asi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso deberia funcionar.

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto, no hay necesidad en este caso de usar imágenes

Answer (score 0):

Has lo siguiente:

```
<v-select 
 multiple 
 v-model="selectComunas" 
 :value.sync="comunas.id" 
 :options="comunas" 
 label="name">
</v-select>
```

y en tu modelo, agrega `selectComunas`:

```
data() {
    return {

        selectComunas:''
    }
  },
```

y si muestras algo como: `<p>{{selectComunas}}</p>` podrás ver los items que has seleccionado.